# How to convert character to unicode?

Tags: unicode

I have this character.

> &#8211

How to convert this character to unicode?
Sorry if it is a silly question.

Comment: In which language do you want to convert it?? If you are using **php** use **utf8_encode('&#8211')**

Comment: In Javascript I think it should be '\u2013'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a silly question, character encoding can be tricky to get your head around. I highly recommend reading [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) (I'm sure you can guess the topic).

Unicode itself isn't an encoding, it's a very long list of characters and code points. What I'm guessing you want to do is display the [dash character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) in some way. Where are you wanting to display or store the data? If it's in a browser, then that representation should work as that's the HTML encoded version. If you want to store it in a database then you'll need to convert that encoded version to a string and then convert that string to whatever encoding the database is using.

Comment: I just coded it loke dash character ty)))

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this source has the encoding in different formats
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm

but each language has its own rules on how to write this in a string/char literal